# MSSQL procedure query return "Cannot insert the value NULL into column"

Tags: php, html, css, sql-server

I have a form of 5 fields. when click on submit button it will fetch Amount against the fields from database MSSQL. Now when i fill form and submit it is giving an error. i have used MSSQL procedure query to execute it. please help me out i am in trouble now.

```
 <div id="middle_pane">
   <div>
      <div id="inner_pane">
    <div id="center_pane">
    <div id="center_inner_pane">
        <div class="txt_content">
     <table width="385" height="200" style=" border:2px solid silver" 
     cellpadding="6px" cellspacing="0px" align="center" border="0"> 
     <form method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/fedex-tariff">
    <tr> 
    <td colspan="2" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; 
    fontsize:50px">Fedex Rate Card</td></tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>Origin</td>
    <td>
        <select name="origin" id="origin" onChange="">
            <option value="pakistan">Pakistan</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <td>Select Origin city </td>
    <td>
        <select name="city_id" id="city_id">
            <option value="">--SELECT CITY--</option>
                <?php 
                 $city  = "select * from branches";
                 $city_query    = mssql_query($city);
                 while ($row_city = mssql_fetch_array($city_query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_city['name'];?>"> <?php echo 
                $row_city['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td>Select Destination </td>
      <td>
        <select name="country_id" id="country_id">
            <option value="">--SELECT Destination--</option>
                <?php 
                 $service= "select * from country";
                 $service_query= mssql_query($service);
                 while ($row_service = mssql_fetch_array($service_query)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_service['Name'];?>"> <?php 
                echo $row_service['Name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Selection of Weight </td>
         <td>
            <div id="wgt">
                <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value="" 
                placeholder="weight...." required="">
            </div> 
          </td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Select Your Service</td>
         <td>
            <select name="service_id" id="service_id">
            <option value="">--SELECT--</option>    
            <?php
            $service_type = "SELECT distinct ServiceTypeId from 
            dbo.IntlZoneCountry where ServiceTypeId IN ('FedEx Cash Tariff 
             Docs','FedEx Box','FedEx Student Package')";
            $res_type   = mssql_query($service_type);
            $cnt_type   = mssql_num_rows($res_type);
            while($row_type = mssql_fetch_array($res_type)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_type['ServiceTypeId'];?>"><?php 
             echo $row_type['ServiceTypeId'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="submit" value="Calculate" name="submit" 
          class="btn"></td>
         </tr>
        </form>
         <table width="385" style=" border:2px solid silver" 
          cellpadding="6px" cellspacing="0px" align="center" border="0"> 
         <tr>
        <td>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
         {
         $city_id       =   $_POST['city_id'];
         $country_id        =   $_POST['country_id'];
         $service_id        =   $_POST['service_id'];
        $weight_id      =   $_POST['weight'];
        if(empty($city_id) || empty($country_id) || empty($service_id) || 
         empty($weight_id)){
          ?><center><?php echo "Please filled all the fields first.";?>
        </center>
         <?php
           } 
        else{
          $s = "[SP_UpdateCNPrice_Int_Tariff] 
          '$weight_id','$city_id','$country_id','$service_id'";

        $result    =  mssql_query($s); 
        while($row   = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
         ?>
        </td>
           </tr>    
         <tr style="background:#00CFFF; color:blue;">
           <td>
            <center>
             <font size="3">
              <?php
                    $val = $row['amount'];
                    $gst = $row['gst'];
                    echo "<strong>"."Rate : "."$".""."&nbsp;".$val.$gst;
               ?>  
                 </font> 
              </center>
               </td>
                 </tr>  
               <tr style="background:#00CFFF; color:blue;"> 
                <td><center> All Rates are Exclusive of 16% GST + 23% fuel 
                 Charges (FSC).</center> </td>
                  </tr> 
                <?php
                     }
                  } 
                   }
                  ?>
                   </table>
                </div>
               </div>
                </div>
               </div>
                </div>
```

[MSSQL Procedure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA3Z5.png)

[Front Display of Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1jBY.png)

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from an insert into one of the # temp tables in your sproc. Can you open the sproc and update your post with the contents?

Comment: actually i didn't create sproc. my colleague create it and share it with me only this line [SP_UpdateCNPrice_Int_Tariff] '1','2','D','FedEx Cash Tariff Docs';

Comment: That's the code to execute your procedure, not the procedure code itself. Again, the error being returned is that you can't insert a NULL into the temp table *inside the sproc*. We can't help you without the stored proc itself.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer sorry i dont understand.

Comment: Go to [YourDatabase]>Tables>Programmability>Stored Procedures>SP_UpdateCNPrice_Int_Tariff, right click and go to Script Stored Procedure as>Create To>New Query Editor Window. Then copy everything and paste/edit your post with the contents.

Comment: i have opened Script Stored Procedure as>Create To>New Query Editor Window but what to copy now it opened blank window?

Comment: Without the stored procedure this is guess work. And since you can't see it on the sql server you obviously don't have permission. The actual error message should be pretty clear. You are trying to insert NULL into a column that doesn't allow NULL. And you might want to take a peek at this article and share it with your colleague. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix